# Using embedded R tool in Prolog

Tags: r, prolog, swi-prolog

I know with using pack 'real', we can use embedded R in Prolog. But I met problems to use this pack. And I didn't find simple examples of using this pack.

Can somebody give a simple example of this pack?

e.g. Loading Prolog values on to R variables and then call R functions on these values (generate a plot by R function or whatever).

Comment: If you were asking for advice about how to write valid R code you would need to define a dataset and a desired process. If you were hoping to get an answer from people who already use R, then you would need to point them to a way to rapidly install Prolog and define a method to do some sort of "Hello, World" operation in that environment. So this appears mainly a request to search out resources for you.

Comment: You would probably have better luck emailing the author of the pack or asking on the SWI-Prolog mailing list. This is a very open-ended question on a very specialized topic.

Comment: You can try to use [pyswip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyswip) or [pyswip3](https://github.com/f0ma/pyswip3) and [pyRserve](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyRserve)  to make connection between Prolog and R through Python layer.

Comment: To explain my question more specifically, can somebody give a sample code of generating xy plot through using 'real' pack in Prolog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is the same as the SWISH version I think so just look here:

http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/Rserve.swinb

and

http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/Rdataframe.swinb